# Is It Possible To Trace Java API Calls In Android ART Using Frida Framework?

Tags: android, android-runtime

I can trace JNI APIs very easily using this code

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("lib.so" , "somefunction"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        args[1] = ptr(0);
        send("somefunction("+Memory.readCString(args[0])+","+args[1]+")");
    },
    onLeave:function(retval){

    } });
```

when I try to trace java functions using the following code nothing returns

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var c = Java.use("java.net.URI");
    c.parseURI.implementation = function () {
        console.log("String1:"+args[0]);
        send("String1:"+args[0]);
        this.parseURI(args[0]);

    } });
```

from Frida website

> Frida currently supports Dalvik, and while most of that code is just
>   interacting with the JNI APIs implemented by the VM, there are some
>   bits that are VM-specific